# Can't access my Apache2 web server

Tags: apache2, webserver

I set up my Apache2 server with Amazon's lightsail. I was able to access it with the external IP given to me by Amazon. I recently shut it down and then started it back up again, changing my public IP. I tried connecting with this new one, but it pointed me back to my old IP.

What gives?

Thanks.

Comment: We need more information. When you changed your public IP, under what authority did you do so? When you try connecting to the new IP did you do it by domain name or directly by IP address? If by domain name, had the DNS records been updated properly?

Comment: I personally didn't change my public IP, by shutting down and then starting my server up again, Amazon changed it. I tried connecting by IP, I don't have a domain yet.

Comment: Then what was it that "pointed me [you] back to my [your] old IP"?

Comment: My browser. On my phone and my computer. When I type in my new public IP, it'll wait a bit, and then it'll send me to the old public IP, which will come up with a this site can't be reached page.